# PHP MySQL プリペアードステートメントのセキュリティについて

Tags: php, mysql, security

以下のようなプリペーアドステートメントを作りました。
id:int型、name:varcher型、area:int型です。
areaは1～10までの数値で住んでいる地位を表すとします。
例えば1=関東、2=関西、3=四国、...

この場合すべての地域のユーザーデータを取得する場合はどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

例えば

```
if($area==0){
  $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM user");
}else{
  $ps=$db->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE area = :area");
  $ps->bindValue(':area', (int)$area, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $ps->execute();
}
```

のようにしてもセキュリティ的に問題ないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

結論から言うと、記載内容の実装でも別に問題ないと思います。

```
$db->query("SELECT id, name FROM user");
```

上記、特にセキュリティ的な問題はないと思います。
※サンプルということなので細かい話は一旦置きます。

ひとつのSQLでまとめるならOR句を使ってやればできると思います。